# TypeScript mapped types to use the value of an object property as the key of a new object using a generic

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm trying to get my head around generics and mapped types. I have an input array of objects `options` that gets passed to `makeOptionsObject`, which returns a single object with key-value pairs where the key is the `property` value, and the value is either the `defaultValue` or empty string.

My problem lies in the `Options` type, as I can't seem to figure out how to generate a return type for the function based on the input argument.

Here's a the code below in a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCAOUCW4IwLwwNoCgb5gG88DT4AnBAU3KgE8AuGAcmSgBsrmAaE0-ACZUAZgEMAruygA1Ue3FUmzACIiJUmABUkHLr1IBffQWL8CFarUYtgoqFQDmIcnR58YR96bMwL8GvRKABaiEAByIMjCSLbIqG4+MEJikjJyCkxQ5ArG+J4AugDcODj0-jAA8ogoYBhE7uRUogLg7HS+lP5WTNDkSGAOxaSNza3tyepp8lQA-D1Z-Q4wAD4wYOIAtgBGNCswWyAgnKJgxQbFpXTlVXGQADyaMFQAHvZgAmg3NVj5AHx1ACUqKByAIHlh1tsaPksMw-AFXPluFoIZsduQYcwJqlZNNmH8LqBILANqIANZUL6oCpbABWwNgmAeT1eVHen2q4F+AAoELcIExND8AJRMKn3IV-DD-bz4BpUKDici1Pk1CAAOkaAnEwCo3O5omAwE2yNV4GF0pg3Nl-HVdsNxo2uX4WDNYHV8Ks+SYbvV2KkuIUMBmMxYCX4BmFyMIkaGBBw5xKOCJ0DgnLANPpwEZMFJFPFEEzDN56YgwsJqCOVHV7BADhLtyL2fLOAA9AAqLzuUhsThKVQpDTaXThsyxRzOazMUf8ELhSJIaKxNWZbJUZ0GHDt1slN1NqDq3tUfCt1swCBBECSAQwCRQEDRdjsW-vFlIVP9GD9exP99siBUDge50gy6qhAIwgEKe56XteayRG+0A4EAA).

```js
const options = [
    {
        property: 'title',
        defaultValue: 'Default Title',
    },
    {
        property: 'category',
    },
    {
        property: 'hasNotifications',
        defaultValue: true,
    },
];

type Option = {
    readonly property: string;
    readonly defaultValue?: string | number | boolean;
};

type Options<T extends Option[]> = Record<T[number]['property'], T[number]['defaultValue']>

const makeOptionsObject = <T extends Option>(options: T[]): Options<T[]> => {
    
    return options.reduce((accum, option) => ({
        ...accum,
        [option.property]: option.defaultValue ?? '',
      }), {});
    
};


const optionObject = makeOptionsObject(options);

console.log(optionObject);
/*
    {
        title: 'Default Title',
        category: '',
        hasNotifications: true,
    }
*/

optionObject.title
optionObject.asdf
```

Ideally the return type of the function would help infer that `optionObject.title` does exist and `optionObject.asdf` does not exist.

I've read the docs for [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and did a fair amount of searching on SO.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgDabN) meet your needs? If so then I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: You're a legend. This is exactly what I was looking for, and I'd greatly appreciate an explainer if you're up for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in order to have any hope of capturing the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `property` properties of the elements of `options`, you will need to change how it is initialized.  Currently it is effectively of type `Option[]` where `property` is just `string`; that is, you're unintentionally discarding the string literal types you care about before we even get started.  The easiest way to preserve this sort of information is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on the initializing value; this gives the compiler a hint that you want to keep the object exactly as initialized and that you'd like much more specific type information:

```
const options = [
    {
        property: 'title',
        defaultValue: 'Default Title',
    },
    {
        property: 'category',
    },
    {
        property: 'hasNotifications',
        defaultValue: true,
    },
] as const;
```

Now we have enough information to proceed.

---

Here's one way to give `makeOptionsObject` a call signature:

```
const makeOptionsObject = <T extends Option>(options: readonly T[]): {
    [O in T as O["property"]]: "defaultValue" extends keyof O ? O["defaultValue"] : ""
} => {
    return options.reduce((accum, option) => ({
        ...accum,
        [option.property]: option.defaultValue ?? '',
    }), {}) as any;

};
```

It's [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of element types of the `options` parameter.  The output type is a [mapped type with key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as); so take the union `T` and iterate over each union member `O`.  For each such member we produce a property type whose key is `O["property"]` and whose value is conceptually `O["defaultValue"]`.  Except that some of your `O` members won't actually have a `defaultValue` property; and if not, the property value will be the `""` string literal type.

Note that the implementation just [asserts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the returned value is of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any), effectively turning off type checking of this value.  I did that because there is absolutely no way to lead the compiler through the type logic to verify that `options.reduce(...)` actually produces a value of the [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) return type.  That means we need to be careful and double-check that the implementation does what the call signature says it does.

---

Okay, let's try it:

```
const optionObject = makeOptionsObject(options);
/* const optionObject: {
    title: "Default Title";
    category: "";
    hasNotifications: true;
} */
```

Looks good.  The compiler knows the `optionObject` has properties `title`, `category`, and `hasNotifications` of the right types.  The `category` property has the default `""` type , while the other properties get their types from the `options` initializer.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=66&pln=19&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBCAOUCW4IwLwwNoCgb5gG88DT4AnBAU3KgE8AuGAcmSgBsrmAaE0-ACZUAZgEMAruygA1Ue3FUmzACIiJUmABUkHLr1IBffQWL8CFarUYtgoqFQDmIcnR58YR96bMwL8GvRKABaiEAByIMjCSLbIqG4+MEJikjJyCkxQ5ArG+J4AujChMKCQUADcMAD0VTAAPAC0DTBgVFQCMFBBSGjOMFTsEFSdQcOgALbwSJzkMADu4Kww5FTjqwBGNCPD7Do0cjDQ5EhgDp10-hA4OPT+MADyiChgGETuK6IC4Ox0vpT+ViYRxODnK7yon2+v2S6jS8ioAH4gVkQTAAD4tcTjTazDHrEAgTiiMBggxgnClaAwcaiADWVEecUg93WACsqMBYJg6pp+gAPexgARoRnPAB8AAoEEyIEwPl8wD8tFh8gBKJjefBYe4wE5aIoirAAIj8AToRvy+SYRphqVk8KN-MFwpg9LoIGEDxgCIexttUntCgtMGtRpwBgwYrepBWUHE5Be0ueEAAdCsBOJgFQJRLRMBgFjuHAnuBVZGYBLNfwUzW8wXxrl+Fgk+AU6arFbi0yU-64QpvT7mAkCAZVUXCKODUUwHRyWTrpTYC2wCz2ZzXjT6aLUKuOVApSXIKqwVUAFQlVBLw+7zka9xsTjW1QpDTaXRGsGkWKOZzWI0f9wQnCSIkGiWJk0ybIqFJGBTyqBdUEJKgU3YEAHAPJkbygY8cDPLx3FIB9FBYZ9YS0HROGHMxvycFwlCo-ggIiKIYjsCDOigxsDBwODrmXLCUyI-AakOIIQEkDoJCgD1pnYacOioPkelgPUTnsdhdiGSAqBwfi2T3FNQgET1hNqCAxIklpIn5ZScCAA)

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution, description, and most importantly, your time. 

With it all making sense now, I’m wondering if this is the right way to do things? It feels a bit outside of what TS is meant to provide but I’m unclear if that is true or not.

Comment: It seems fine to me; nothing particularly "crazy" is happening in my opinion.  Most non-trivial generic functions involving mapped types or conditional types will need type assertions so that part doesn't raise huge red flags for me.  It really depends on your use cases though.